# Using a list in multiple Functions

Tags: python, list, function, maya

Is it possible to use a list created in one function in a separate function?

I've created a list of discs in this function:

```
def create_discs():

    disc_list=['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']
```

I would then like to use this list in a different function

```
def move_discs

    cmds.move(disc_list[1], 0, 0, 5)
```

I get this error when trying to do so:

```
NameError: file <maya console> line 48: global name 'disc_list' is not defined #
```

I'm using Autodesk Maya

Comment: The usual way to do this (i.e. maintain state) is with a class.

Comment: is there any other way? just that I haven't covered using classes yet. if there isn't i can research classes :)

Comment: Return the list from the create_discs function, and pass it into the move_discs function.

Comment: how do i pass it into the move_discs function?

Comment: The list itself is an instance of the built-in list class. If you return the list from one function and pass it into another as an argument you can retain or modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Classes to maintain state, then you may want to have a `global` variable or you can return the list from `create_list()`.

**Using global variable**:

```
disc_list = []

def create_list():
    global disc_list

    disc_list = ['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']

def move_discs
    cmds.move(disc_list[1], 0, 0, 5)
```

Note that using global variables is not encouraged.

**Returning list from `create_list()`**:

```
def create_list():
    return ['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']

def move_discs():
    disc_list = create_list()
    cmds.move(disc_list[1], 0, 0, 5)
```

But I don't think this will of much help to you as you probably need to keep the state of your list throughout the program.

Comment: looks like i may have to use a class!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return that list in your first function:

```
>>> def create_discs():
    disc_list=['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']
    return disc_list


>>> def move_discs():
    l = create_discs()
    print(l)
>>> move_discs()
['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the first function return the wanted list and then use it anywhere you like:

```
def create_discs():
    disc_list = ['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']
    return disc_list

def move_discs():
    disc_list = create_discs()
    cmds.move(disc_list[1], 0, 0, 5)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: hi thank you for answering! unfortunately my first function includes more than just that list so this doesn't work, i should have mentioned this in my question, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do what you're trying to do.

If you want to merely create the list using `create_discs` once in order for it be used in `move_discs`, you can modify `create_discs` to return the list it creates, and then call `create_discs` within `move_discs`:

```
def create_discs():
    return ['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']

def move_discs():
    cmds.move(create_discs()[1], 0, 0, 5)

move_discs()
```

If you want to have the created list saved so that it can be used throughout the program, you can again have `create_discs` return its list, and have it save to a variable. This variable can then be accessed by `moved_discs` or any other function:

```
def create_discs():
    return ['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']

def move_discs():
    cmds.move(saved_list[1], 0, 0, 5)

saved_list = create_discs()
```

I'm not sure if you have researched function arguments yet, but they are a feature of functions which support the very behavior you're trying to achieve:

```
def create_discs():
    return ['disc0', 'disc1', 'disc2']

def move_discs(list):
    print(list[1])

saved_list = create_discs()
move_discs(saved_list)  # This will output 'disc1'

saved_list = ['new0', 'new1', 'new2']
moved_discs(saved_list)  # This will now output 'new1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are persistent objects on their own. If you return the list from one function you can manipulate it in others:

```
def get_list():
    return [1,2,3,4]


def remove_last_item( the_list):
    the_list.remove(the_list[-1]) #  remove the last entry


def insert_something(the_list, item):
    the_list.insert(item, 0)

my_list = get_list()
print my_list
# [1,2,3,4]

remove_last_item(my_list)
print my_list
# [1,2,3]

insert_something(my_list, 0)
print my_list
# [0,1,2,3]
```